# reshape data with different numeric columns

Tags: r, reshape

I'm trying to plot different graphics comparing the HPIs to the Median index. First, I had the same data I have in this example, but without the last three columns, and I reshaped it with the following code, to have one column with the median and one column for the three HPIs

```
 df %>% 

 pivot_wider(names_from = Index, values_from = Value) %>% 
 pivot_longer(starts_with("HPI"), names_to = "Index", values_to = "Value")
```

Now, I need the other three columns to add a confidence interval in the graphic but I can't seem to make it work.

This is an example of my data

```
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Index,    ~Value, ~Operation, ~Month, ~SD, ~lower, ~upper, 
  "HPI1",    0.9,    "Sale", "01/2020", 0.00224245, 0.9788445 ,0.9876349,
  "HPI1",    1.1,    "Rent", "02/2020", 0.00227729, 1.0323418, 1.0412688,
  "HPI2",    0.89,   "Sale", "01/2020", 0.00645641, 1.1494260, 1.1747352,
  "HPI2",    1.12,   "Rent", "02/2020", 0.00645641, 1.1494260, 1.1747352,
  "HPI3",    0.85,   "Sale", "01/2020",0.00732540, 1.1376065, 1.1663221,
  "HPI3",    1.22,   "Rent", "02/2020", 0.00645641, 1.1494260, 1.1747352,
  "Median",  0.91,   "Sale", "01/2020",0.00732540, 1.1376065, 1.1663221,
  "Median",  1.02,   "Rent", "02/2020",0.00732540, 1.1376065, 1.1663221,
  "HPI1",    0.9,    "Sale", "02/2020",0.00224245, 0.9788445 ,0.9876349,
  "HPI1",    1.1,    "Rent", "03/2020", 0.00645641, 1.1494260, 1.1747352,
  "HPI2",    0.89,   "Sale", "02/2020", 0.00227729, 1.0323418, 1.0412688,
  "HPI2",    1.12,   "Rent", "03/2020", 0.00645641, 1.1494260, 1.1747352,
  "HPI3",    0.85,   "Sale", "02/2020",0.00224245, 0.9788445 ,0.9876349,
  "HPI3",    1.22,   "Rent", "03/2020",0.00732540, 1.1376065, 1.1663221,
  "Median",  0.91,   "Sale", "02/2020",0.00227729, 1.0323418, 1.0412688,
  "Median",  1.02,   "Rent", "03/2020",0.00732540, 1.1376065, 1.1663221,
  "HPI1",    0.9,    "Sale", "03/2020", 0.00645641, 1.1494260, 1.1747352,
  "HPI1",    1.1,    "Rent", "04/2020",0.00224245, 0.9788445 ,0.9876349,
  "HPI2",    0.89,   "Sale", "03/2020",0.00732540, 1.1376065, 1.1663221,
  "HPI2",    1.12,   "Rent", "04/2020",0.00227729, 1.0323418, 1.0412688,
  "HPI3",    0.85,   "Sale", "03/2020", 0.00645641, 1.1494260, 1.1747352,
  "HPI3",    1.22,   "Rent", "04/2020",0.00224245, 0.9788445 ,0.9876349,
  "Median",  0.91,   "Sale", "03/2020",0.00227729, 1.0323418, 1.0412688,
  "Median",  1.02,   "Rent", "04/2020",0.00732540, 1.1376065, 1.1663221)
```

thank you very much

Comment: What are you trying to plot? could you describe the expected output graph: Possibly a line graph with four lines for HPI1-3 and Median values (the y axis) by Month (x axis), facetted by Operation? And some indicator for the upper and lower limits for the Value.

Comment: What do the lower and upper values relate to? they generally seem to be both more than or less than `Value` but to not seem to "bracket" `Value`

Comment: I'm sorry. I just made up this data and the numbers don't make sense now that I think bout it. lower and upper are the boundries for the confidence interval. I need to facet_grid by index and operation, but I also need the median as another column, so that I can have a single plot for each HPI + the median

Comment: Ah, that helps, the suggested solution manages this without pivot wider or longer. Not tried to incorporate the upper or lower data as this seems a bit out of kilter in any case that should flow pretty naturally if required.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a possible approach without having to use `pivot_wider` and `pivot_longer`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)

# month as date format

df <- 
  df %>% 
  mutate(Month = my(Month))

# All cases of HPI index by Month and Operation to join with Median only data to create a separate data frame for the facetted Median line

df_hpi <- 
  df %>% 
  filter(Index != "Median") %>% 
  select(Index, Month, Operation)

# Median data frame for all facetting cases: Index and operation by month and value
df_med <- 
  df %>% 
  filter(Index == "Median") %>% 
  rename(dataset = Index)%>% 
  right_join(df_hpi, by = c("Month" = "Month", "Operation" = "Operation"))

# HPI data only
df1 <- 
  df %>% 
  filter(Index != "Median")
  
# All together in the call to ggplot

ggplot(df1, aes(Month, Value, group = Index))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_line(data = df_med, aes(colour = "Median"))+
  facet_grid(Operation~Index)+
  labs(colour = NULL)+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you are trying to do something like this: a line and a ribbon around (confidence interval).
But the values of your column "lower" doesn't seem to be correct.

Instead I have used the column "SD".

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)


df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Index,    ~Value, ~Operation, ~Month, ~SD, ~lower, ~upper, 
  "HPI1",    0.9,    "Sale", "01/2020", 0.00224245, 0.9788445 ,0.9876349,
  "HPI1",    1.1,    "Rent", "02/2020", 0.00227729, 1.0323418, 1.0412688,
  "HPI2",    0.89,   "Sale", "01/2020", 0.00645641, 1.1494260, 1.1747352,
  "HPI2",    1.12,   "Rent", "02/2020", 0.00645641, 1.1494260, 1.1747352,
  "HPI3",    0.85,   "Sale", "01/2020",0.00732540, 1.1376065, 1.1663221,
  "HPI3",    1.22,   "Rent", "02/2020", 0.00645641, 1.1494260, 1.1747352,
  "Median",  0.91,   "Sale", "01/2020",0.00732540, 1.1376065, 1.1663221,
  "Median",  1.02,   "Rent", "02/2020",0.00732540, 1.1376065, 1.1663221,
  "HPI1",    0.9,    "Sale", "02/2020",0.00224245, 0.9788445 ,0.9876349,
  "HPI1",    1.1,    "Rent", "03/2020", 0.00645641, 1.1494260, 1.1747352,
  "HPI2",    0.89,   "Sale", "02/2020", 0.00227729, 1.0323418, 1.0412688,
  "HPI2",    1.12,   "Rent", "03/2020", 0.00645641, 1.1494260, 1.1747352,
  "HPI3",    0.85,   "Sale", "02/2020",0.00224245, 0.9788445 ,0.9876349,
  "HPI3",    1.22,   "Rent", "03/2020",0.00732540, 1.1376065, 1.1663221,
  "Median",  0.91,   "Sale", "02/2020",0.00227729, 1.0323418, 1.0412688,
  "Median",  1.02,   "Rent", "03/2020",0.00732540, 1.1376065, 1.1663221,
  "HPI1",    0.9,    "Sale", "03/2020", 0.00645641, 1.1494260, 1.1747352,
  "HPI1",    1.1,    "Rent", "04/2020",0.00224245, 0.9788445 ,0.9876349,
  "HPI2",    0.89,   "Sale", "03/2020",0.00732540, 1.1376065, 1.1663221,
  "HPI2",    1.12,   "Rent", "04/2020",0.00227729, 1.0323418, 1.0412688,
  "HPI3",    0.85,   "Sale", "03/2020", 0.00645641, 1.1494260, 1.1747352,
  "HPI3",    1.22,   "Rent", "04/2020",0.00224245, 0.9788445 ,0.9876349,
  "Median",  0.91,   "Sale", "03/2020",0.00227729, 1.0323418, 1.0412688,
  "Median",  1.02,   "Rent", "04/2020",0.00732540, 1.1376065, 1.1663221)

df %>%
  mutate(Month = my(Month),
         ymin = Value - 2*SD,
         ymax = Value + 2*SD) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(
    x = Month,
    y = Value,
    group = Operation,
    color = Operation
  )) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(
    x = Month,
    ymin = ymin,
    ymax = ymax,
    group = Operation,
    fill = Operation
  ),
  alpha = 0.3) +
  facet_wrap(~ Index) +
  theme_light() +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL)
```

[image]